# Quotient Map of the Torus is Not Open

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, open-map

I am having some trouble with the following problem:

> Define a relation on the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ as follows: for every $x,y\in[0,1]$, let $(x,y)\sim(x,y)$, $(0,y)\sim(1,y)$, and $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$. Show that the quotient map $\pi:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to([0,1]\times[0,1])/\sim$ is not an open map.

*My knowledge of the problem:* I know that a mapping $f:(X,\tau_{X})\to (Y,\tau_{Y})$ is open if and only if for any open set $\mathcal{O}\in \tau_{X}$, we have $f(\mathcal{O})\in\tau_{Y}$. I also know that the map $\pi$ is just the map which sends $x\mapsto [x]$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$ under $\sim$. Finally, I think (not entirely sure) that this quotient should give us the torus.

*Where I'm Stuck:* I am having difficulty figuring out how to show that a set is not open in the quotient space. I think I might have to start with an open ball in $[0,1]^{2}$ and then show that its image is not necessarily open in the quotient space. I'm not sure if this is right though.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\pi([0,1/2)\times [0,1/2))$ is not open in the quotient space (which is indeed a torus).

Comment: Okay! But because it's open in the original space, we can conclude that the map isn't open?

Comment: @WarTurtle Right.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this makes more sense now.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Could you elaborate as to why it is not open in the quotient space?

Comment: @WarTurtle This can be seen directly at a torus. :-) For a formal proof we may note that a sequence $\{\pi(1-\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n)\}$ from its complement converges to its point $\pi(0,0)$, which is impossible for open sets.